# Below condition is not working in xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the below condition that I have wriiten in xsl below..

as i have getting an value in xml of  fpml:tradeId now it can be there in xml or it can not be there for example as shown below..

```
<fpml:tradeId tradeIdScheme=""></fpml:tradeId>
or it can contain value also
<fpml:tradeId tradeIdScheme="">10381159400</fpml:tradeId>
```

as advise i have change the implementation to but still not working ..

```
                <xsl:if test = "fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier[2]/fpml:tradeId = ' '">
                 <xsl:value-of select="'null'" />
                </xsl:if>                   
            </ContractID>
```

so to deal with this problem i have come up with this below xsl , now the problem comes is that for the cases where tradeId is not there in xml it is not putting null string please advise is my below implementation of 
xsl is correct

```
                <xsl:if test = "fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier[2]/fpml:tradeId != ' '">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier[2]/fpml:tradeId,'-')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier[2]/fpml:tradeId,'-')" />
                </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier[2]/fpml:tradeId" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:if test = "fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier[2]/fpml:tradeId = ' '">
                 <xsl:value-of select="'null'" />
                </xsl:if>                   
            </ContractID>
```

as advise new implemetaion done but it is still not working..

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier[2]/fpml:tradeId)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier[2]/fpml:tradeId,'-')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier[2]/fpml:tradeId,'-')" />
                </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier[2]/fpml:tradeId" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:if test = "fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier[2]/fpml:tradeId = ' '">
                 <xsl:value-of select="'null'" />
                </xsl:if>                   
            </ContractID>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're testing for

```
fpml:tradeId = ' '
```

which it doesn't in your example - the value of your `fpml:tradeId` is the empty string, not a string containing a space.  Instead of comparing the value against `' '` for the first case you could use a test of

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(
    fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier[2]/fpml:tradeId)">
```

In XPath a string coerces to a boolean by treating it as false if the string is empty and true if it isn't, so the test will pass if the `tradeId` value contains at least one non-whitespace character, and fail if it is completely empty or contains only whitespace.

For the second case

```
<xsl:if test="not(normalize-space(
    fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier[2]/fpml:tradeId))">
```

would give you the reverse test - true if the string is all whitespace or empty, false if it isn't (or just use a `choose` with an `otherwise` clause instead of two opposing `if` tests).

Comment: i have edited the question can you please advise over it

Comment: moreover the xml tag is like <fpml:tradeId tradeIdScheme=""></fpml:tradeId>

Comment: well the tradeid tag doesn not contain value at all as i can see

Comment: @user1620642 Your edit has replaced the first test (the `test="... != ' '"`) but not the second one, which is still comparing for an exact match against `' '` (a single space).