# Testing conditions in XSLT with xsl:when

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the below xsl tag in which i am fetching out the values of fpml:periodMultiplier and fpml:period as shown below ...
tags in xml are :-

```
<fpml:periodMultiplier>1</fpml:periodMultiplier>
<fpml:period>Y</fpml:period>
```

extracting in xsl as shown below

```
<Payindextenor>
<xsl:value-of select="../fpml:calculationPeriodDates
                        /fpml:calculationPeriodFrequency
                        /fpml:periodMultiplier" />
<xsl:value-of select="../fpml:calculationPeriodDates
                        /fpml:calculationPeriodFrequency
                        /fpml:period" />
</Payindextenor>
```

so the value of Payindextenor is 1Y

now i want to put the null check in this tag since it may happen that in coming xml there can be no value for fpml:periodMultiplier and fpml:period also.

so i have come up with below xsl implementation in which i have tried that if any of the value is null then it should print null pls advise is it correct one :-

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="../fpml:calculationPeriodDates
                    /fpml:calculationPeriodFrequency
                    /fpml:periodMultiplier
                  != ' ' 
                  and 
                  ../fpml:calculationPeriodDates
                    /fpml:calculationPeriodFrequency
                    /fpml:period 
                  != ' '">
    <xsl:value-of select="../fpml:calculationPeriodDates
                             /fpml:calculationPeriodFrequency
                            /fpml:periodMultiplier" />
   <xsl:value-of select="../fpml:calculationPeriodDates
                           /fpml:calculationPeriodFrequency
                           /fpml:period" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="'null'" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "is null"?  This code is checking whether the target values are equal to a string containing a single space, which will fail for a missing element or one with a (completely) empty value.

Comment: @IanRoberts Lets say the value comes in xml like as <fpml:periodMultiplier></fpml:periodMultiplier>
<fpml:period></fpml:period>

Comment: @IanRoberts so as shown in above comment that if there in no value in the input xml for these two tags

Comment: So if you want to test for the elements having an empty string value, why are you comparing against a non-empty string (`' '`)?

Comment: There are two valid answers to your question. Please accept one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the same situation as in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882502/below-condition-is-not-working-in-xsl) - you're comparing against the (non-empty) string `' '` containing a single space, when what you actually want is to check for empty strings.  And you can use the same solution as I suggested for that question, and test using `normalize-space` (which treats empty strings and strings containing only whitespace as "false" and anything else as "true"):

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="normalize-space(../fpml:calculationPeriodDates
                    /fpml:calculationPeriodFrequency
                    /fpml:periodMultiplier)
                  and 
                  normalize-space(../fpml:calculationPeriodDates
                    /fpml:calculationPeriodFrequency
                    /fpml:period)">
    <xsl:value-of select="../fpml:calculationPeriodDates
                             /fpml:calculationPeriodFrequency
                            /fpml:periodMultiplier" />
   <xsl:value-of select="../fpml:calculationPeriodDates
                           /fpml:calculationPeriodFrequency
                           /fpml:period" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="'null'" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

This will handle cases both where `fpml:periodMultiplier` or `fpml:period` elements are absent, and where they're present but empty.

Answer (score 1):

As Ian Roberts has said, comparing a node to a single space is very different from checking for "null", but assuming you want to display "null" when both `periodMultiplier` and `period` are blank, you can do this:

```
<xsl:variable name="freq" 
         select="../fpml:calculationPeriodDates/fpml:calculationPeriodFrequency" />
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$freq/fpml:periodMultiplier != '' or 
                  $freq/fpml:period != ''">
    <xsl:value-of select="$freq/fpml:periodMultiplier" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$freq/fpml:period" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text>null</xsl:text>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: The OP's subsequent comments suggest they want to check for present-but-empty rather than absent.